# Could we see a lower dimension within our universe?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions

My question refers to the fact, that, say if our universe were to be sitting on a 4 (spatial) dimensional plane, that we cannot see, then within our universe could there be a point mass in which 1 or 2 (spatial) dimensions could exist. We may not be able to see them, this could be a result of our world only consisting of 3 Dimensions. Although the computer screen, for example, is 2Dimensional, it sits on a 3 Dimensional object. Could a 2Dimensional object or world, exist in our 3D plane without having a 3D object that it is displayed upon, I have illustrated it below to build a clearer picture...

[image: Point Mass]

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Have a look at http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/forum/polytope/  for four dimensional (euclidean dimensions) objects appearing in three dimensions. We have no physical evidence of such objects. Of course when time is the fourth dimension we are all projections into the three dimensional world.

Comment: No, it doesn't. What precisely are you asking here, anyway? .   What do you mean " a lower dimension within our univeorse " ?   A 2 - dimensional object ?   What do you think you're staring into?!

Comment: Well, does your lower-dimensional object interact in any way with our known 3+1-dimensional universe?

Comment: I don't mean a 2D object like looking at a computer screen I was thinking more in the sense of a singularity. This singularity is something that one is unable to see due to the fact that it is special in sown form, after considering your point though, a 4th dimension or higher could be in the point mass but I still think that it would be difficult to see a 1D object. And the object would interact in a 1 space and 1 time dimensional way not 3 space and 1 time.

Comment: The grammar, spelling, and punctuation of the question make it incomprehensible.

Comment: I changed it so I don't sound quite so illiterate, I'm sorry you hated it so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the string theory tag in your question, you're probably asking for something like [a brane world](http://www.enwp.org/brane_world). In such a scenario, standard model interactions, which are mediated by open strings, and are thus bound to the branes. According to some research ([e.g.](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9906064)), it is possible to ensure general relativity also behaves normally on the brane despite the higher dimensionality of spacetime.